# Is it possible to create a CLHeading object in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to implement a drop-in location manager subclass to allow me to pass heading data to the iphone simulator, similar to the unimotion/accelerometer hack. Unfortunately, according to the [CLHeading docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/index.html), everything is read only and there's no initialiser which allows the heading to be set. Is there a way to force the creation of a populated instance of CLHeading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a dynamically typed language, you can create your own class (for example,`MyFakeHeading`) and as long as it responds to all of the same selectors that `CLHeading` does, you can simply cast it as a `CLHeading` and pass it as a parameter instead. And, since you only need to fake out your own code, you don't even need to implement all the functionality of `CLHeading`, just the parts your are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using private methods (private or enterprise app) you can add `CLHeading+Init.h`to your project:

```
@interface CLHeading (Init)

- (id)initWithHeading:(double)heading accuracy:(double)accuracy;

@end
```

I'm using it in my location simulator https://github.com/maciekish/MockingPlace

***Warning! This will get your app rejected from the App Store!***

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to subclass `CLHeading` and override the property getters and setters you care about.

Here's an example in Swift:

main.swift:

```
import CoreLocation

class SubclassOfCLHeading: CLHeading {
    open override var magneticHeading: CLLocationDirection {
        get {
            print("getter invoked")
            return 12345
        }

        set {
            print("setter invoked \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}

let heading = SubclassOfCLHeading()

print(heading.magneticHeading)

heading.magneticHeading = 54321
```

Running this yields…

```
getter invoked
12345.0
setter invoked 54321.0
```

Here's the same thing in Objective-C:

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SubclassOfCLHeading.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        SubclassOfCLHeading *heading = [[SubclassOfCLHeading alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"%f", heading.magneticHeading);

        heading.magneticHeading = 54321;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

SubclassOfCLHeading.h:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface SubclassOfCLHeading : CLHeading

@property(nonatomic) CLLocationDirection magneticHeading;

@end
```

SubclassOfCLHeading.m:

```
#import "SubclassOfCLHeading.h"

@implementation SubclassOfCLHeading

- (CLLocationDirection)magneticHeading {
    NSLog(@"getter invoked");
    return 12345;
}

- (void)setMagneticHeading:(CLLocationDirection)magneticHeading {
    NSLog(@"setter invoked %f", magneticHeading);
}

@end
```

In either example, if you want to store the values passed to the setter, you can declare your own property for storage and name it something different than the overridden property.

Comment: You can't override with a stored property!

Comment: @WilliamGrand I updated my answer to show how this is possible. Happy to clarify further if needed. Hope it helps.